# How can I set a return code from the command line without exiting my SSH client?

Tags: command-line, alias

I'm really new to Unix and currently I need to make an alias that checks a file whether it is regular and readable. If its irregular, then I need to return 1 as the exit code and not test if its readable. If its unreadable, I need to return 2 as the exit code.

```
alias test="if [ ! -f filename ] ; then echo 'Irregular file'; exit 1 ; fi; if [ ! -r filename ]; then echo 'Unreadable file'; exit 2; fi;
```

The problem is now when I run it, the exit will close my entire client. Any way to get around this?

Comment: You could write an alias that *wraps a shell command* (`alias mytest="sh -c ' ... '"`) that performs the tests and exits with the specified status

Answer (score 4):

As this is the first link when doing a search in Google:

If you wrap the exit in brackets

```
(exit 2)
```

then it will set a return code by exiting the sub-shell in the brackets, and won't exit your current shell.  You can then test for that code using $? as normal

```
alias mytest="if [ ! -f filename ] ; then echo 'Irregular file'; (exit 1) ; elif [ ! -r filename ]; then echo 'Unreadable file'; (exit 2); fi"
```

Answer (score 2):

A shell function should be able to `return` a value you like:

```
checktype() {
    if [ ! -f "$1" ] ; then 
        echo 'Irregular file'
        return 1
    fi 
    if [ ! -r "$1" ]; then 
        echo 'Unreadable file'
        return 2 
    fi
    return 0
}
$ checktype /dev/stdin ; echo $?
Irregular file
1
```

Also, `test` is an awful name for an alias or a function, since it's a standard (builtin) utility.

---

> I realize that alias is an awful choice, but currently it's being required by a professor.

Okay, this changes things a bit. My suggestion would be to show the prof a more suitable solution, and explain why the simple one doesn't work.

But in case that won't work, and you really *must* use an alias, consider that the return value is actually just the return value of the last command that was executed. You should be able to rig up something that returns a value you want...

(If it's homework, I don't think it would be fair to give a full solution immediately. Spoilers below.)

> Hint: You already used a command that returns an arbitrary value.

Answer (score 0):

`alias` is a bad choice here. Put those lines into a bash script file.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f filename ];
 then echo 'Irregular file'; exit 1 ;
fi;
if [ ! -r filename ];
 then echo 'Unreadable file'; exit 2;
fi;
```

It will work as intended.

Comment: I realize that alias is an awful choice, but currently it's being required by a professor. I really appreciate your time and response though.

Comment: Wait. You can not return values from `alias`. It is not a function, it is text substitution only. May be you can write values to a temp file to be read later. But you can not return value because you can not call alias.